# Filter files in DirectoryIterator output

Tags: php

I'm working on a script that gets file modified times, and takes an optional arg that if filled has an array with a list of files to check rather then every file. How could I go about just getting the data for those files in a script like this:

```
$filesObject = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path));

foreach ($filesObject as $key => $object)
{
    $checkFile = filemtime($object->getPathname());
    $num++;
    $alertFiles[$num] = array('name' => $object->getPathname(),
                              'time' => $checkFile);
}
```

edit: this code is in a function where $filesArray is the array of file names that can be passed.

Comment: what are the criteria for the files to filter? There is no `$filesArray` in your code. Show us how it looks please.

Comment: I'm don't quite understand the question, so I'll go into more depth. Currently as the code shows, it goes through all files in $path, I'm looking for a way to filter to only check, or show, certain files if $filterArray has a file or files listed in it.

Comment: There is no `$filterArray` in your code. What does it contain? "file" in what format? Absolute path? Just the filename? Patterns? SplFileObject?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't include the whole code because it's lengthy. The code above is in a function that has an optional arg called $filesArray that if supplied, would be an array listing files to check rather then all files. The format would be along the lines of array('filename', 'subdir/filename'.. and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your Iterator in a custom [Filter Iterator](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php) (to foster reuse)

```
class FileFilter extends FilterIterator
{
    protected $_files;

    public function __construct($iterator, array $files)
    {
        $this->_files = $files;
        parent::__construct($iterator);
    }

    public function accept()
    {
         return !in_array($this->current(), $this->_files);
    }
}
```

If `accept` returns `FALSE` the current element is not considered in the iteration. Since you give very little information about your `$filesArray` contents, you might have to change the `accept` logic to make it work for your code.